# Show Gridview inside a Gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with 2 columns ([+] and [data]). On click of [+] sign it opens a girdview inside the same gridview.

Now, in child gridview I have a link button, on click of that I display some data. On postback the gridview retains its original position, I want to show the child gridview as it is.

Code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvNeverTouchedQuartile" class="form-table" Width="100%" OnRowCommand="grvNeverTouchedQuartile_RowCommand"
                                                                AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="grvNeverTouchedQuartile_RowDataBound"
                                                                DataKeyNames="QuartileType">
                                                                <Columns>
                                                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnNTQuartile" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quartile") %>'
                                                                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuartileType") %>' CommandName="NeverTouched"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                                                                            <img alt="Image not available" style="cursor: pointer" src="../images/plus.png" />
                                                                            <asp:Panel ID="pnl_NTChildGrid" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                                                                                <table>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td>
                                                                                            <div style="overflow: auto;">
                                                                                                <asp:GridView ID="grdNTInsuranceData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="grdNTInsuranceData_RowCommand">
                                                                                                    <Columns>
                                                                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Insurance Name">
                                                                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblNTQuartileType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuartileType") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblNTInsuranceName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("InsuranceName") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                                                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnNTInsuranceQuartile" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("InsuranceNameDetails") %>'
                                                                                                                    CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="NeverTouchedInsurance"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                                    </Columns>
                                                                                                </asp:GridView>
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </table>
                                                                            </asp:Panel>
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quartile[Count - $Value]">
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblNTQuartile" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quartile") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                            <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnNTQuartile" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quartile") %>'
                                                                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuartileType") %>' CommandName="NeverTouched"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                </Columns>
                                                            </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Do you have tried code? then provide it here to get better help.

Comment: @Aria, I have edited my question. please have a look at it.

Comment: So you say your main problem is refreshing page after clicking on link button in child grid and after refresh child grid closed?

Comment: @Aria yes exactly.

Comment: Did my answer give you the clue ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways (This is not with code it is just my suggestions, there are codes over internet or it is based on experience) so in my opinion you can use one of below cases:

1- You should use `UpdatePanel` to prevent refreshing page and put the grid inside `UpdatePanel`, just for sample like below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelId" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server"  >
    <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:GridView ID="gvPrList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="false"
           AllowSorting="false" CssClass="list-table" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header">
           <Columns>
         <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnNTInsuranceQuartile" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("InsuranceNameDetails") %>'
                                                                                                                   CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>' CommandName="NeverTouchedInsurance"></asp:LinkButton>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

2- the `runat` of `lnkbtnNTInsuranceQuartile`  is `server` which main after it's click post-back will be occurred so page get refreshed for this you can change your `lnkbtnNTInsuranceQuartile` to HTML element such as `<div><a class="x">click here</a><span class="detail"/></div>` and then instead of `lnkbtnNTInsuranceQuartile` click use `ajax` and then update details Span something like :

```
    $('.x').click(function () {
    var $me = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Your Web Method address',
        data: { youData},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //update span here
            $me.parent().find('.details.'.html(your response);
        },
        error: function (x, e) { 
        }
    });
});
```

3- Use client-side Grid not ASP.Net GridView

4- Add collapsed `th`'s id into `localstorage` and after page load open it again...

5- etc...

all three above steps can be implemented based on your scenario...

Hope will help you